# How can I check that assignment of const_reverse_iterator to reverse_iterator is invalid?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following:

```
using vector_type = std::vector<int>;
using const_iterator = typename vector_type::const_iterator;
using const_reverse_iterator = typename vector_type::const_reverse_iterator;
using iterator = typename vector_type::iterator;
using reverse_iterator = typename vector_type::reverse_iterator;

int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<iterator, const_iterator>); // passes
    static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<reverse_iterator, const_reverse_iterator>); // fails
    static_assert(std::is_assignable_v<reverse_iterator, const_reverse_iterator>); // passes
}
```

I can check that assignment of `iterator{} = const_iterator{}` is not valid, but not an assignment of `reverse_iterator{} = const_reverse_iterator{}` with this type trait.

This behavior is consistent across [gcc 9.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3zYvqTuhxUF9OiNZ), [clang 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5myhfmpl05HsEdqY), and [MSVC 19.00.23506](http://rextester.com/KUIL48585)

This is unfortunate, because the reality is that `reverse_iterator{} = const_reverse_iterator{}` doesn't actually compile with any of the above-mentioned compilers.

#### How can I reliably check such an assignment is invalid?

This behavior of the type trait implies that the expression

```
std::declval<reverse_iterator>() = std::declval<const_reverse_iterator>()
```

is well formed according to [meta.unary.prop], and this appears consistent with my own attempts at an `is_assignable` type trait.

Comment: By the by, but [you can't assign singular iterators to each other.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32760445/560648)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But this question is purely on the type level. As far as I understand, singularity is not meaningful at type level but only in evaluated expressions. The problem also [persists](https://godbolt.org/z/Okvpxu) even for non-singular assignment.

Comment: @Max Yes, hence, "by the by"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This trait passes because the method exists that can be found via overload resolution and it is not deleted.

Actually calling it fails, because the implementation of the method contains code that isn't legal with those two types.

In C++, you cannot test if instantiating a method will result in a compile error, you can only test for the equivalent of overload resolution finding a solution.

The C++ language and standard library originally relied heavily on "well, the method body is only compiled in a template if called, so if the body is invalid the programmer will be told".  More modern C++ (both inside and outside the standard library) uses SFINAE and other techniques to make a method "not participate in overload resolution" when its body would not compile.

The constructor of reverse iterator from other reverse iterators is the old style, and hasn't been updated to "not participate in overload resolution" quality.

From [n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), 27.5.1.3.1 [reverse.iter.cons]/3:

> ```
>   template<class U> constexpr reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<U>& u);
> ```
>
> Effects: Initializes current with u.current.

Notice no mention of "does not participate in overload resolution" or similar words.

---

The only way to get a trait you want like this would be to

1. Change (well, fix) the C++ standard
2. Special case it

I'll leave 1. as an exercise.  For 2., you know that reverse iterators are templates over forward iterators.

```
template<class...Ts>
struct my_trait:std::is_assignable<Ts...> {};

template<class T0, class T1>
struct my_trait<std::reverse_iterator<T0>, std::reverse_iterator<T1>>:
  my_trait<T0, T1>
{};
```

and now `my_trait` is `is_assignable` except on reverse iterators, where it instead tests assignability of the contained iterators.

(As extra fun, a reverse reverse iterator will work with this trait).

I once had to do something very similar with `std::vector<T>::operator<`, which also blindly called `T<T` and didn't SFINAE disable it if that wasn't legal.

---

It may also be the case that a C++ standard library implementation can make a constructor which would not compile not participate in overload resolution.  This change could break otherwise well formed programs, but only by things as ridiculous as your static assert (which would flip) or things logically equivalent.

Comment: Writing my own trait seems like the best approach for the interim. Your solution [works great](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JNKpY5zPs5vZvGuZ) thanks.

Comment: @AndyG I see you chose a better name.  Wise.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's just a question of constraints. Or lack thereof. Here's a reduced example with a different trait:

```
struct X {
    template <typename T>
    X(T v) : i(v) { }

    int i;
};

static_assert(is_constructible_v<X, std::string>); // passes
X x("hello"s); // fails
```

Whenever people talk about being SFINAE-friendly - this is fundamentally what they're referring to. Ensuring that type traits give the correct answer. Here, `X` claims to be constructible from anything - but really it's not. `is_constructible` doesn't actually instantiate the entire construction, it just checks the expression validity - it's just a surface-level check. This is the problem that `enable_if` and later Concepts are intended to solve.

For libstdc++ specifically, [we have](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h#L150-L153):

> ```
> template<typename _Iter>
> _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR
> reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
> : current(__x.base()) { }
> ```

There's no constraint on `_Iter` here, so `is_constructible_v<reverse_iterator<T>, reverse_iterator<U>>` is `true` for all pairs `T`, `U`, even if it's not *actually* constructible. The question uses assignable, but in this case, assignment would go through this constructor template, which is why I'm talking about construction.

---

Note that this is arguably a libstdc++ bug, and probably an oversight. There's even a [comment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h#L146-L149) that this should be constrained:

> ```
> /**
>  *  A %reverse_iterator across other types can be copied if the
>  *  underlying %iterator can be converted to the type of @c current.
>  */
> ```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Barry. As far as I can tell, there's nothing I can do short of waiting for the library implementors to constrain it?

Comment: @AndyG You could write an explicit trait just for this, that's about it (do _not_ specialize `is_assignable`!). You could also write a libstdc++ patch! They don't bite.

Comment: Does the standard mandate that this constructor not participate in overload resolution?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont [It does not](http://eel.is/c++draft/reverse.iter.cons)... that's arguably a standard library bug then.

Comment: @Barry I wonder if a proposal *permitting* SFINAE in all such cases, followed by a proposal demanding it in the following standard, would be practical.  Ie, "if the result of instantiating a std library template function, template's method, a template method, or constructor is an ill-formed program, the library MAY make the method, function or constructor not participate in overload resolution", upgrading to MUST in the following standard (assuming no issues are found in the interval).  Basically, easier than finding each case and adding "does not participate in overload resolution".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not sure, but I think it may already be allowed to add constraints like that? Any valid program will already pass those constraints anyway

Comment: @Barry Almost any valid program.  `static_assert(std::is_assignable_v<reverse_iterator, const_reverse_iterator>);` is a valid statement under the standard; if you add SFINAE to reverse iterator it fails.  From such a boolean condition I can construct programs that behave in arbitrarily different ways based on if that participates in overload resolution or not.  If you added explicit permission in the standard to do SFINAE-style overload removal then the result becomes implementation defined instead of a standard violation.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have trouble imagining Mr. Wakely losing sleep over breaking that assertion :-D