# Ambiguous call when overloaded methods take reverse iterators in arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, ambiguous, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to write an overloaded method that returns non-const result only when both the object on which it is called is non-const and iterator passed in the argument is non-const.
(Think of it like the standard methods `begin()` and `begin() const` that additionally take an iterator argument.)

I made a version for normal iterators with no problems.
However, for some reason, when I'm trying to do the same for reverse iterators, I get a compilation error about an ambiguous function call.

Here's a *minimal* example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    void bar(std::vector<int>::iterator x) {}
    void bar(std::vector<int>::const_iterator x) const {}

    void baz(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator x) {}
    void baz(std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator x) const {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar(v.cbegin());  // OK
    foo.baz(v.crbegin()); // ambiguous
}
```

For some reason it compiles if I remove `const` from the second method `baz`.
It also works in C++20 but currently I cannot use that version.

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ebM1P5bsq)

How can I make the function `baz` work in analogous way to the function `bar`?

Comment: fyi: looks like a `std` library implementation issue if you add `-stdlib=libc++` it compiles - https://godbolt.org/z/s4jfzjWfE  Both GCC and MSVC also have a problem - live - https://godbolt.org/z/ozdzqY41Y

Comment: Note: you can also add `void baz(std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator x) {}` to fix this issue... My guess would be that `crbegin()` doesn't return a `const_reverse_iterator` for some reason, but something implicitly convertible to one making the conversions of the `Foo` to const and the conversion of the operand an ambiguity the compiler won't resolve, but I may be wrong here...

Comment: It seems the ambiguity comes from [template<class U> constexpr reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<U>& other)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator) constructor and it indeed was addressed in c++20 only: `This overload participates in overload resolution only if U is not the same type as Iter and std::convertible_to<const U&, Iter> is modeled (since C++20)`

Comment: Related/dupe: [How can I check that assignment of const_reverse_iterator to reverse_iterator is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279473/how-can-i-check-that-assignment-of-const-reverse-iterator-to-reverse-iterator-is)

Comment: The quick fix is:  `Foo const& cfoo = foo; cfoo.baz(v.crbegin());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh the joys of overloading resolution rules and SFINAE.

The methods are equivalent to free functions:

```
void bbaz(Foo&,std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator){}
void bbaz(const Foo&,std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator){}
```

and your usage becomes:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    Foo foo;
    bbaz(foo,v.crbegin());
}
```

The arguments do not exactly match either call:

- `foo` is `Foo&`, not `const Foo&`
- `v.crbegin()` return `vector::const_reverse_iterator` which **is just a different instantiation of the same `std::reverse_iterator` template as `vector::reverse_iterator`**.

  - `reverse_iterator`->`std::reverse_iterator<vector::iterator>`
  - `const_reverse_iterator`->     `std::reverse_iterator<vector::const_iterator>`

#### Cause of ambiguity

Now, the issue is that `std::reverse_iterator`'s ctor is not SFINAE-friendly until C++20:

```
template< class U >
std::reverse_iterator( const std::reverse_iterator<U>& other );
```

I.e. there is a viable candidate converting `std::reverse_iterator<T>` to `std::reverse_iterator<U>` between any `T-U` pairs. In this case for `T=vector::const_iterator`, `U=vector::iterator`. But of course the template instantiation fails later because it cannot convert `const int*` to `int*`.

Since that happens in the template function's body, not the signature, it is too late for SFINAE and overloading considers it a viable candidate function, hence the ambiguity since both calls require one implicit conversion - although only the second one would compile.

This is explained [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279473/how-can-i-check-that-assignment-of-const-reverse-iterator-to-reverse-iterator-is), making this one essentially a duplicate of that question but it would be IMHO cruel to mark it as such without an explanation which I cannot fit into a comment.

C++20 fixes this omission and SFINAEs that ctor - [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator):

> This overload participates in overload resolution only if U is not the same type as `Iter` and `std::convertible_to<const U&, Iter>` is modeled (since C++20)

#### Solution

As pointed in the comments by @Eljay, forcing `const Foo&` at the call site is one option, one can use C++17 `std::as_const`:

```
#include <utility>
std::as_const(foo).baz(v.crbegin());
```

Fixing this at definition is more tricky, you could use SFINAE to actually force these overloads but that might be a hassle. @fabian 's solution with adding a third overload without `const` method qualifier seems easiest to me:

```
void Foo::baz(std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator x) { 
    return std::as_const(*this).baz(x); 
}
```

It works because now it is a better (exact) match for non-`const` `Foo`s than the still considered `vector::reverse_iterator` which would not compile anyway.