# Copy constructor for reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator) lists 3 possible constructors to *reverse_iterator*, or as it is formally described as:

```
std::reverse_iterator<Iter>::reverse_iterator
```

Which, if I am not mistaken, means that reverse iterator is a template, acting as an adapter for the underling *Iter*, which could be of any type, i.e. either *const_iterator* or *iterator*.

*const_reverse_iterator*, is thus another name for a *reverse_iterator* with an underlying *Iter* of type *const_iterator*.

I think. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Anyway, The 3rd constructor is listed there, as:

```
template< class U >
constexpr reverse_iterator( const reverse_iterator<U>& other );
```

Then, it adds:

> The underlying iterator is initialized with that of *other*. This
> overload participates in overload resolution only if *U* is not the same
> type as *Iter* and std::convertible_to<const U&, Iter> is modeled (since
> C++20)

As far as I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582018/ambiguous-call-when-overloaded-methods-take-reverse-iterators-in-arguments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279473/how-can-i-check-that-assignment-of-const-reverse-iterator-to-reverse-iterator-is), this was added in order to eliminate the constructor from participating in overload resolution for constructing a *reverse_iterator* from a *const_reverse_iterator*, which wouldn't compile because of their underlying iterators, i.e. *const_iterator* couldn't possibly be assigned to *iterator*.

What I don't understand is the language in the quote above (please bear with me, as I am very new to C++), and I quote again the above:

1. What does it mean "only if U is **not the same** type as Iter"? Does it mean that I can not copy-construct a *reverse_iterator* from another *reverse_iterator* if their underlying iterators are of the same type. In other words, if I have a *reverse_iterator* adapter for `std::vector<int>::iterator`, can I not construct another *reverse_iterator* adapter with the **same** underlying iterator from it? (I checked, and it is of course possible!).
2. I also don't understand in the quote above, which reads: `std::convertible_to<const U&, Iter> is modeled`.
   What exactly does it exclude. Why, for example, couldn't the standard use instead `std::convertible_to<U, Iter>` (without the *const&*) to check if the underlying iterators are compatible?

Thanks

Comment: For 1. you are missing that there is still an implicit copy constructor overload.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks. Why is it important to exclude the implicit copy constructor from this template.

Comment: Am I correct, that this template overload is only used to construct a *const_reverse_iterator* from a *reverse_iterator*, or to construct a reverse_iterator from another one, where the underlying iterators are both compatible, i.e. both *int pointers*, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean "only if `U` is not the same type as `Iter`"?

`reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<U>& other)` is the so-called *converting constructor*, which allows us to construct a `reverse_iterator` from other `reverse_iterator` with different template parameters, if the two underlying iterators are compatible.

A simple example is to use `reverse_iterator<int*>` to create a `reverse_iterator<const int*>`.

> can I not construct another `reverse_iterator` adapter with the same
> underlying iterator from it?

Of course you can, because `reverse_iterator` has a copy constructor and is copyable.

> couldn't the standard use instead `std::convertible_to<U, Iter>`
> (without the `const&`) to check if the underlying iterators are
> compatible?

Because the converting constructor accepts a const reference to a `reverse_iterator<U>`, which makes its underlying iterator `const`-qualified as well.

Comment: what is the difference between `std::convertible_to<const U&, Iter>` and `std::convertible_to<U, Iter>`. Is there any type `U` where the first is false and the 2nd is true? For some reason, `std::convertible_to<const int&, int>` is true, and the same is true for every type that I checked.

Comment: For any type that is copyable but unmovable, only `std::convertible_to<const T&, T>` will be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. Can an iter really be unmovable? I know that "pure" arrays are unmovable (and also uncopyable, the same as atomics). Are there any other examples?

Comment: This is just an example. While such case is uncommon for iterators, it is still possible. For example, when the constructor of the `Iter` type that accepts `U&&` is deleted. The constraint is not about commonness, it's about correctness.

Comment: thanks. And one last thing, what was the point in the quote above to explicitly exclude the implicit copy constructor (i.e. when *U* and *Iter* are of the same type) from this template constructor?

Comment: The copy constructor is a copy constructor, and the conversion constructor is a conversion constructor, they have completely different meanings. The former tends to be the default and should not be affected by the latter.